# Finding the % Contribution Of Change In A Hyperbolic Parabola

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've got the following equation, where $z$ and $x$ are both variables:

$$y = (zx)+(x+z)$$

What I want to know is: when z and x both change, what percentage of the change in y is driven by the change in z and what percentage is driven by the change in x?

You can stop reading here and answer that if you want, but I've provided my current though process and some examples below in case that helps:

If z and x were to change by equal amounts, then each variable should account for 50% of the total change in y since both z and x are performing the same operations. As an example:

Let's say that z and x both increase by 0.10. In that case, y would increase by 0.21.

Since  x and z each increased by the same amount and perform the same operations, then each variable contributed to 50% of the total change, or 0.105 points.

But is that true across all changes? If z increased by 0.2 and x increased by 0.1, did z account for 66% of the total change in y?

Comment: No that is not correct. But for $z = x$, there is symmetry.

Comment: Thanks for the response; so how would I calculate it for scenarios where z != x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one "intuitive" idea: use directional derivatives.

Say you want to increase $x$ by $\Delta x = a$ and increase $z$ by $\Delta z = b$. Let $\vec{u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} (a,b)$ be the unit vector in the direction $(a,b)$. To make things simple, assume $(a,b)$ is a unit vector, so that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = 1$, and we won't have to have the square roots in our equations.

Then the directional derivative $D_{\vec{u}}y$ measures the infinitesimal change in $y$ as the point $(x,z)$ moves in the direction $(a,b)$. The formula for directional derivative is:

$$ D_{\vec{u}} y = a \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} $$

You could say the "contribution" from changing $x$ is the term $a \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ and the contribution from changing $z$ is $b \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$. Then one possible heuristic way of saying the "percent of total change coming from $x$" would be
$$ \frac{a \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}{a \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial y}{\partial z}} $$
and similarly for $z$.

In your example, you said increase $x$ by $0.1$ and $z$ by $0.2$. The unit vector $\vec{u}$ in this direction is $\vec{u} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(1,2)$. This means put $a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}$ and $b=\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}$ in the formulas above. Since $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 1+z$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} = 1+x$, the directional derivative is:
$$ D_{\vec{u}} y = \frac{3+2x+z}{\sqrt{5}} $$
The percentage coming from $\Delta x$ is then $\frac{1+z}{3+2x+z}$, and the percentage coming from $\Delta z$ is $\frac{2(1+x)}{3+2x+z}$.

So you see, it's not enough to just say what are $\Delta x$ and $\Delta z$. The answer also depends on what point $(x,z)$ you start at.

Comment: Ok thank you for that, super helpful. I've been playing around with it, and I've come up with the following:

Let's say a = 5, b = 10. Then: 

$-a/(a^2+b^2)^(3/2) = -0.01789$ and 
$-b/(a^2+b^2)^(3/2) = -0.07155$. With those values, we can say:

-0.01789/-0.07155 = 0.8, and the reciprocal is 0.2. That those values always seem to add up to 1 regardless of the values of a or b suggests that this might be a different way of measuring the relative contributions coming from a and b in terms of percentage.

Does that make sense? Or is that a flawed way to look at it?

Thanks again

Comment: I don't understand your computation. Is that $3/2$ an exponent? It looks like the left parenthesis is raised like an exponent, but the rest is not. Even so, I don't get the numbers you do when I compute it. Also, the reciprocal of 0.8 is not 0.2, so I don't know what you mean there.

Comment: Looking back on this it was not structured clearly. Let me try again, starting from a different perspective (and with better formatting). 
Let's say we're starting at the point x = 0, z = 0. 
Then let's again increase x by 0.1 and z by 0.2, so the rest of the example holds as the same. 
In that case, the percentage chanage coming from Δx is 1/3, or 33%, and the percentage change coming from Δz is 2/3. or 67%.
Now, to clarify that I'm understanding the underlying math correctly (next comment)

Comment: Let's say that, starting at the point x = 0, z = 0, x increases by 5 and z increases by 10:
Then, in the percent change equation, we'd have: a = $ 5/\sqrt(125) $ and b = $ 10/\sqrt(125) $ 
Plugging those values into the equation, the percentage change coming from Δx would be $ 5(1+z)/(15+5z+10x) $ 
Starting at the point (0, 0), that's again 33% for x and 67% for z. 
So at the starting point (0,0), does $ a/(a+b) $ always equal the percentage coming from Δx?

Comment: Yes, if you plug in $x=z=0$, then the percentage equations become $a/(a+b)$ and $b/(a+b)$.

Comment: Great, I understand now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found the post helpful, could you please upvote the post?

Comment: Done. Since I'm new I guess it doesn't display but I also marked it as answering the question.